# Super-interface in a partial class in WCF

Tags: wcf, interface, partial-classes

I am creating a WCF service with multiple interfaces say "IService" as my main interface (Service Contract) and other interfaces added based on my modules.
like - "IStudent", "IClass", "ITeacher" etc.

So what i am planning is like this -

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IKCCWebService : IStudent, IClass, ITeacher
{}
```

and use my service like this -

```
public partial class MyService : IKCCWebService
{} 

public partial class MyService : IStudent
{
   // Student interface implemented
} 

public partial class MyService : IClass
{
   // Class interface implemented
}
```

And so on. If i do this i am getting error - "MyService does not implement interface member "IKCCWebService"".

I dont want to implement all interfaces at one shot so i am taking this approach.

Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what partial classes are for.

Partial classes don't allow you to implement "part" of a class or interface.  Partial classes are just a method to allow parts of a class to be defined in different *places*.  When the compiler builds your project, it finds all of the partial definitions for a class and mashes them together into the complete definition.

For example, this code:

```
partial class MyClass: BaseClass
{
}

sealed partial class MyClass: IFirstInterface
{
    public void FirstMethod(){ }
} 

public partial class MyClass: ISecondInterface
{
    public void SecondMethod(){ }
}
```

really translates to this:

```
public sealed class MyClass : BaseClass, IFirstInterface, ISecondInterface
{
    public void FirstMethod(){ }
    public void SecondMethod(){ }
}
```

All of the members, modifiers, implemented interfaces, and inherited classes get applied to the class when it is built.

The typical usage for this is when part of a class is dynamically generated (e.g. by a tool or designer) and part of the class is manually generated.  The class can be declared partial and split between two files - one that you don't touch (because the tool could regenerate it at any time) and one that the tool doesn't touch, where you put all of your code.

---

In your case, declaring multiple partial classes serves no purpose.  Since one of your partial definitions includes `MyService : IKCCWebService`, the `MyService` class is required to define **all** of the members defined by `IKCCWebService`.

If you don't want to implement the logic for all the interfaces in one shot, you don't have to.  Just define the required interface methods with a single line: `throw new NotImplementedExeption();`  The compiler doesn't care what the methods do, so long as the methods are defined.